# How to call items from JSON API and added to TabBar - Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I want to create (News App), I have a list of category in the website, I followed this [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data), so I need to add website's category to my `TabBar`, exactly like this image:

[image]

How can I do that?

And I want to change direction from left to right to from right to left, How can I do that?

**Code:**

`Category Class:`

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Category> fetchCatgeory() async {
  final response = await http.get("url");

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Category.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load category');
  }
}

class Category {
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Category({this.id, this.title});

  factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Category (
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }

}
```

`HomePage Class:`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:munaw3_news/extra/json_file.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();

  final Future<Category> catg;

  HomePage({Key key, this.catg}) : super(key: key);

}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  _HomePageState();

  int a = 0;
  Future<Category> catg;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    catg = fetchCatgeory();
  }
  bool isPressed = false;

  _pressed() {
    var newVal = true;
    if(isPressed) {
      newVal = false;
    } else {
      newVal = true;
    }

    setState((){
      isPressed = newVal;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: catg.toString().length,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Image.asset('assets/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
            bottom: TabBar(

              tabs: [
                // Tab(text: catg[0],),
                // Tab(text: catg[1],),
                // Tab(text: catg[2],),
                // Tab(text: catg[3],)
              ],
            ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(

        children: [
          // Tab(text: catg[0],),
          // Tab(text: catg[1],),
          // Tab(text: catg[2],),
          // Tab(text: catg[3],)
        ],

      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        elevation: 0,
        color: Colors.grey[900],
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 5,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.grey[900],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
              child: Container(
                height: 60,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  child: new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.info), color: Colors.grey[600], iconSize: 30,
                                  disabledColor: Colors.white,
                                  onPressed: a==3 ? null : () => setState(() {
                                    a=3;
                                  })),

                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.local_mall), color: Colors.grey[600], iconSize: 30,
                                  disabledColor: Colors.white,
                                  onPressed: a==2 ? null : () => setState(() {
                                    a=2;
                                  })),

                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark), color: Colors.grey[600], iconSize: 30,
                                  disabledColor: Colors.white,
                                  onPressed: a==1 ? null : () => setState(() {
                                    a=1;
                                  })),

                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), color: Colors.grey[600], iconSize: 30,
                                  disabledColor: Colors.white,
                                  onPressed: a==0 ? null : () => setState(() {
                                    a=0;
                                  })),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      ),),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: No...! :( @Sarah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it, first create a file named it `category.dart`, and in a file create a class:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Category {
  int id;
  String title;

  Category({
    this.id,
    this.title,
  });

  static Future<List<Category>> getCategories() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get("JSON API Url");

    List<Category> list = [];

    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);

        for (var map in map['categories']) {
          list.add(Category(id: map['id'], title: map['title']));
        }
      }
    } catch (e, _) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

And creating a file name it `list_news.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:munaw3_app/model/category.dart';

class ListNews extends StatefulWidget {
  ListNews({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListNewsState createState() => _ListNewsState();
}

class _ListNewsState extends State<ListNews> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Category>>(
      future: Category.getCategories(), //NOT Recommended
      builder: (c, s) {
        if (s.hasData) {
          List<Tab> tabs = new List<Tab>();

          for (int i = 0; i < s.data.length; i++) {
            tabs.add(Tab(
              child: Text(
                s.data[i].title,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ));
          }
          return DefaultTabController(
            length: s.data.length,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Image.asset('assets/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
                bottom: TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  tabs: tabs,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (s.hasError) print(s.error.toString());
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
              child: Text(s.hasError ? s.error.toString() : "Loading...")),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And finally, for directional of `TabBar` you should change the localization of your app to support any country and support fro right to left (RTL), first go to `pubspec.yaml` and new pub in (dependencies):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

And finally back to `main.dart` file and add these code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:munaw3_app/views/list_news.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [const Locale("ar", "AE")], // Here you can add any language you need
      home: ListNews(),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you’re storing your JSON data, Categories, somewhere in a list, right? Then you’ll need to setup your `TabController` so that it can sync with the updated data. Here’s a simplified example:

You might need to change to:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
```

Then, assuming Tabs/TabBarViews will be initialized with stuff that you've retrieved from your API call:

```
List<Widget> myTabs = [...];
List<Widget> myTabsContent = [...];
```

Instead of using `DefaultTabController`, you’ll need to create your own `TabController`, and initialize it in `void initState()`:

```
TabController myTabController;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  var lastIndex = myTabs.length - 1;
  myTabController = new TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: myTabs.length,
      initialIndex: lastIndex
  );
}
```

A simplified version of your Widget build will look like this, so modify as needed:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
      bottom: TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        controller: myTabController,
        tabs: myTabs.toList(),
      ),
    ),

    body: TabBarView(
      controller: myTabController,
      children: myTabsContent.toList(),
    ),
  );
}
```

And as for this:

> “*And I want to change direction from left to right to from right to
>   left, How can I do that?*”

If I understand correctly, this is basically `initialIndex`, set it to the last index if you want the selector to be on the right most tab.